# Redirect using <p:commandButton>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Following line should save a new item and redirect to another page. So far, it saves correctly, but it doesn´t redirect. No errors or warnings.

```
<p:commandButton id="savebutton" ajax="false" value="#{msg['addCategory.save']}" actionListener="#{addCategoryController.doSave()}" />
```

Code behind:

```
 public String doSave(){       
    categoryAddEvent.fire(categoryProducer.getSelectedCategory());
    return Pages.LIST_CATEGORIES;
}
```

As I said, the first line executes correctly, the second one doesn´t seem to do anything. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You'd better use `action` instead of `actionListener` to perform navigation. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener

Comment: Where is your 'onclick'? Please change the subject

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it in two ways:

- **Navigation**:

Calling an action, with the commandButton component set as ajax false, and the bean method returning a String (as you already have).

***xhtml page:***

```
<p:commandButton id="savebutton" ajax="false" value="#{msg['addCategory.save']}" action="#{addCategoryController.doSave()}" />
```

- **Redirect**:

Calling an actionListener, with the commandButton component set as ajax true, with the bean method not returning value, but instead performing itself the redirection to the desired page.

***xhtml page:***

```
<p:commandButton id="savebutton" ajax="true" value="#{msg['addCategory.save']}" actionListener="#{addCategoryController.doSave()}" />
```

***java bean:***

```
public void doSave(){       
    categoryAddEvent.fire(categoryProducer.getSelectedCategory());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(Pages.LIST_CATEGORIES);
}
```

Comment: If you look further, my first jsp (i set jsp as an example, as he can use xhtml or whatever he wants), I call the bean method using 'action' instead of 'actionListener' (as he does).