# How do I create a button that executes a function and redirects directly after pressing it?

Tags: jsp, jsf, primefaces, navigation

I created this button and want it to call the function in `action=""` while also redirecting to a new page (displayed in the comment).

```
<p:commandButton icon="pi pi-pencil" value="Edit"
          styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-primary"
          action="#{notificationService.editNotificationInList(notification)}"/><!-- outcome="/create"/-->
```

So far I know I can use `<p:button>` to only redirect (without executing any functions).

Comment: If your `action` returns a String then Faces will try to map that to a URL and you can use `?faces-redirect` to tell it to redirect so in your Java method add `return "mypage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true` to redirect to the mypage.xhtml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect using <p:commandButton>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647525/redirect-using-pcommandbutton)

Comment: @stefan-dan yes it does, but melloware's solution worked as well